# AMD driver doesn't load after rebooting vm with GPU passthrough on virt manager

Tags: linux, virtualization, virt-manager, gpu, amd

I'm having an issue with GPU passthrough, using virt manager on Debian 11. It's a very specific question, but i hope that someone can help me with this. I have an RX 5500XT GPU, and i passthrough it following the tutorial available on the Arch wiki guide (link bellow). It's basically to load the vfio driver on the GPU, so the host system don't use it, then i can set it to a virtual machine (VM). It works very well on the first time that i boot the host and the Windows 10 VM, but if i need to reboot the VM, the AMD driver doesn't load, and the only way to fix this is rebooting the Debian host system too. Is there any way to fix this so i don't have to reboot the host?

Arch wiki guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#top-page

I tried to change the PCI port of the GPU, to reinstall the AMD drivers on the VM, to reboot VM more than once until it load, but this problem wasn't solved.